# Pycharm 2017 docker support for debugging

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I have a question regarding the docker for mac native support in pycharm 2017.1 EAP. 
Can i configure the python interpreter to point to the currently running one in a docker container?

My problem is that now, when i configure the python interpreter , i can only point it to a `image` , it will create a `container` based on that image when i run the project and delete it when i stop it. This way i can install dependencies to this project only if i rebuild the image from a Dockerfile which is really time consuming.

Another solution would be to configure PyCharm NOT to delete the container when i stop the project, this way i can `SSH` to the container from terminal or even from pycharm and install dependencies from the command line.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar.  I can start my containers from PyCharm and the debugging works fine but it takes significantly more time to start or restart django after some changes. Did you find a way to attach PyCharm's debugger to a process running in a container?

Comment: No, the process stills goes into running a container each time